# How to fix error 'Object doesn't support property or method 'getScreenCTM'' in Internet explorer broweser using D3 tip.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 tip.js ,

```
function getScreenBBox() {
var targetel   = target || d3.event.target,
    bbox       = {},
    matrix     = targetel.getScreenCTM(),
    tbbox      = targetel.getBBox(),
    width      = tbbox.width,
    height     = tbbox.height,
    x          = tbbox.x,
    y          = tbbox.y,
    scrollTop  = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop,
    scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
}
```

I am getting this error in Internet Explorer `Object doesn't support property or method 'getScreenCTM'`  in Internet explorer browser. On mouse-enter of tree node tool-tip us displaying and on mouse-leave tool-tip is hidden. But the display position of tool-tip is not changing.

Comment: Which version of IE?  It's only supported in [IE9 and up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Mark Getting error 'Object doesn't support property or method 'getScreenCTM''  in Internet explorer 11

Comment: Are you sure IE is not running on "compatibility mode"?  Go to developer tools, Emulation tab, and look at Document mode.  Also, make sure to include `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`  in the head section of your HTML page.

Comment: @Mark resolved error, as variable targetel  was getting different SVG element (i.e SVGTspanElement and SVGTextElement) in Internet explorer.

Comment: To clarify things, IE's SVGTspanElement doesn't have the getScreenCTM() function. You have to go up in the parent hierarchy and find the first SVGTextElement and use the function on that.

Answer (score 0):

In a practical sense, and if you use compilation for your project, you might try to install polyfill package, that provides ES5 compatibility

```
npm i --save core-js
```

or

```
yarn add core-js
```

Then to add at the top of your entry point of your project

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support

Answer (score -1):

For me this syntax is working fine

1. "d3": "5.4.0",
2. "d3-tip": "^0.9.1",

.on('mouseover', (d, i, n) => tip.show(d, n[i]))